# How can i format XML to desired XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml below. i tried some xsl code for transform to desired output. But I could not be successful. Grouping and selecting specific nodes was too hard
 tag 'A''s values are constant.They can be only 'Math'and 'Phys' (except class name). i have to group these values with class name.

input:

```
<sheet>
   <Row>
      <A>Class:X</A>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <A>Math</A>
      <E>10</E>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <A>Phys</A>
      <E>14</E>
    </Row>
      <Row>
      <A>Class:Y</A>
    </Row>
      <Row>
      <A>Math</A>
       <E>8</E>
      </Row>
      <Row>
       <A>Phys</A>
       <E>12</E>
      </Row>
    </sheet>
```

desired output:

```
 <sheet>
    <ROW>
      <class_type>X</class_type>
      <math>10>/math> 
      <phys>14>/phys> 
    </ROW>
     <ROW>
      <class_type>X</class_type>
      <math>8>/math> 
      <phys>12>/phys> 
    </ROW>
</sheet>
```

My attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:root"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/s0:root">
    <ns0:Sheet>
                <xsl:for-each select="s0:Row">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(s0:A/text(),'Class:')">
                        <ns0:class_type>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(s0:A/text(),'Class:')"/>
                        </ns0:class_type>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="contains(s0:A/text(),'Math')">
                        <ns0:math>
                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:E/text()"/>
                        </ns0:math>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="contains(s0:A/text(),'Phys')">
                        <ns0:phys>
                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:E/text()"/>
                        </ns0:phys>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:Sheet>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry for my english but i am tring for a week. I read all Xslt documents and examples. SO i have wrote code MYself. I do not know why you get such an impression

Comment: You have not shown us the XSLT you wrote as your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: This looks like a grouping problem (do a search). Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I have a limitation for this. It is complex integration between two diffrent platforms. So i cant use XSLT 2.0 or i cant add any XML attributes on input XML

Comment: Will they always come in groups of three {Class:N; Math; Phys}?

Comment: Yes they will. I tried to numbering after if condition but i couldnt use variables. there is no dynamic variable for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/sheet">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[contains(A, 'Class:')]">
            <ROW>
                <class_type>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(A, 'Class:')"/>
                </class_type>
                <math>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Row[A='Math'][1]/E"/>
                </math> 
                <phys>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Row[A='Phys'][1]/E"/>
                </phys> 
            </ROW>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming that every "Class" row has a "Math" and a "Physics" rows following it before the next "Class" row comes along.

Comment: My xml is more complicated then my sample xml.But You gave me an idea.i found follow sibling like that following-sibling::*[contains(s0:G/text(),'Math')]/E/text() thx for your help